# How to set mimeType when use files export of google-drive-api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I use `[google-drive-sdk]`,I see how to export file [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export).

I know `fileId` and `mimeType` these two items are required.

When I set `mimeType` to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`,then I click
the button `EXECUTE`,the response is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "The requested conversion is not supported.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "convertTo"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The requested conversion is not supported."
 }
}
```

It seems that mimeType I set up incorrectly,how to set mimeType?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Docs files cannot be exported as the mimeType of Google Docs. In your case, that is ``application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet``. The reason of the error is due to this mimeType. You can see the mimeTyps which can be exported by [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get). When you put ``exportFormats`` to ``fields``, you can see the mimeTypes. For example, when you put ``application/json`` to ``mimeType`` at Files: export, you can see the PDF data at the result screen. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: In this method,what should I fill in mimeType to allow the operation to pass?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. If ``this method`` you say is "Files: export", for example, how about putting ``application/json`` instead of ``application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet``?

Comment: I used `application/json`,but the error is still exists.

Comment: I'm sorry. That was ``application/pdf``. It was my mistake.

Comment: This is helpful.

Comment: Also you can see the mimeTypes which can be exported. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22exportFormats%22%7D You can execute by clicking  the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS Tanaike said,when I use [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export),I set `text/csv` to `mimeType`,then the response has no error.

Now you can see right response:

[image]

In fact,use [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) can get detailed download information.
For example,in node `exportLinks`:

> "exportLinks": {
>     "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=YpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA&exportFormat=ods",
>     "text/tab-separated-values": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=YpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA&exportFormat=tsv",
>     "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=YpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA&exportFormat=pdf",
>     "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=YpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA&exportFormat=xlsx",
>     "text/csv": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=YpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA&exportFormat=csv",
>     "application/zip": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=YpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA&exportFormat=zip",
>     "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=YpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA&exportFormat=ods"
>    }